# How I can get stored procedure which contains a specific word?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change in where clause because I join with wrong table in many stored procedures in SQL, so I can't find the way to get quicker solution for get query list which contains that word in query window with SSMS also need that stored procedure name has specific number.

I just not get any solution because I stuck there how I select that contains in stored procedure with specific name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS ObjectName,
definition AS ObjectDefinition
FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%_[0-9]'
```

above code is for check **sp name ends with** '_' and Number

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS ObjectName,
definition AS ObjectDefinition
FROM   sys.sql_modules 
WHERE  definition LIKE '%A.Some_ID = B.Some_ID%'
```

above code is for check **sp Contains Name like**

Answer (score 0):

Information_schema's routine_definition has the text of your stored procedures.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES]
 WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%specific_word%'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this query to search all text in SP's in the system tables.  NOTE:  It also searches comments.

```
SELECT Distinct SO.Name
FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
AND SO.Type = 'P'
AND SC.Text LIKE '%TBLRELATIONSHIP%'
ORDER BY SO.Name
```

Comment: I suggest one use `sys.procedures` and `sys.sql_modules` instead of the deprecated backwards compatibility views.

Comment: The use of `NOLOCK` doesn't really make sense here either; I hope you don't just put it against *every* object you reference.